# Setting Edit text next to every Item, which is populating from array

Tags: android

I have a Dialog window like the one shown in picture, and I have requirement of adding one EditText(to take quantity) next to every item, any possible ways to achieve this...?

[image: want to add EditText next to every item]

I have tried creating seperate view and setting it to AlertDialog, but getting single edittext at bottom..

Is there any possible ways that I can add EditText next to every item in the checklist, bec items here are populating from one one Array Items[], with

```
      DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener itemsDialogListener = 
      new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                selectedItems.add(Items[which]);
            else
                selectedItems.remove(Items[which]);
                                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                            for(CharSequence item : selectedItems)
                        stringBuilder.append(item + ",");

                            selectItems.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    };

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(this);
View v1=li.inflate(R.layout.itementry, null);//itementry view has one EditText
builder.setTitle("Select Items");
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colours, checkedItems, itemsDialogListener);
builder.setView(v1);    //By setting this line only one EditText is visible at 
                              the bottom of alert dialog.   
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using custom layout in dialog view may be with listview & your array adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
     Use this code to create Edit Text



     final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     final EditText input = new EditText(this);
     alert.setTitle("Enter the Number of Items");
     alert.setView(input);
     //final String s=input.getText().toString();
     alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
     {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
      {
        int i=arg2;
        values[i]= input.getText().toString().trim();
      }
     });
     alert.show();
```